# How to convert a folder with images into an Excel File using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have a folder full of pictures that are all named the same way.

file names:
..\name_ID.

I want to create a spreadsheet and put the name, ID and a link to the picture into separate columns.

Should use openpyxl, xlsxwriter or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm providing an answer that shows how you can achieve this using xlsxwriter.  It creates a spreadsheet that has the name and the ID and a link to the  associated picture in three separate columns.

The answer uses urllib.request so that it is reproducible (this module is not necessary, I've just put it in there to download three test images).  I've also set the directory to the current directory, which you could modify as you desire.  Also, in my answer, I've set it to only look for .png files but you can adjust to look for other files formats too.

```
import urllib.request
import xlsxwriter
import os


#comment out the next 4 lines if you don't want to download 3 pictures
url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/43/Ipswich_Town.svg/255px-Ipswich_Town.svg.png'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "pica_1.png")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "picb_2.png")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "picc_3.png")


dir_wanted = os.getcwd()
#uncomment the following line if you don't want the current directory
#dir_wanted = "C:\\users\\doe_j"


file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(dir_wanted) if file.endswith('.png')]
full_path_list = [dir_wanted + '\\' + file for file in file_list]

name_list = []
num_list = []

for item in file_list:
    temp_list = item.rpartition('_')
    name = str(temp_list[0])
    num = str(temp_list[2].rpartition('.')[0])
    name_list.append(name)
    num_list.append(num)


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('pics_and_links.xlsx')
ws = workbook.add_worksheet('Links')

#adding column titles and making them bold
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
ws.write('A1', "Name", bold)
ws.write('B1', "Number", bold)
ws.write('C1', "Link", bold)

#putting the three lists we made into the workbook
for i in range (0, len(full_path_list)):
    row_num = i + 2
    ws.write('A%d' % row_num, name_list[i])
    ws.write('B%d' % row_num, int(num_list[i]))
    ws.write_url('C%d' % row_num, full_path_list[i])

#Set the width of the column with the links in it
ws.set_column(2, 2, 40)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much you really helped me out with this !

Comment: Great.  Glad it helped.

Comment: this is nice.... how would one insert the actual pictures themselves into the excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with openpyxl or xlsxwriter, but if I look into the documentation of openpyxl I imagine the program will be something like this

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from scipy.misc import imread

wb = Workboo()
ws = wb.active

img = imread('image.jpg', mode='RGB')
for i in range(len(img)):
    for j in range(len(img[0])):
        # TODO a method to set turn (3, 1) into 'D2'
        index = excel_coordinate(i, j)
        # TODO a method to change RGB in a hex value, perhaps imread also support hex, not sure
        hexval = RGB2hex(img[i][j])
        cel = ws[index]
        cel.PatternFill("Solid", fgColor=hexval)
```

Comment: Sorry for answering late, really apreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

files_dir = '/home/username/files_dir' # here should be path to your directory with images
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(files_dir, '*'))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'id', 'hyperlink'])

for i, full_filename in enumerate(files):
    filename = os.path.basename(full_filename)
    name, id_ = filename.split('_')
    id_ = os.path.splitext(id_)[0] # remove file extension from id_
    hyperlink = '=HYPERLINK("file:///{}")'.format(full_filename)
    df.loc[i] = [name, id_, hyperlink]

df.to_excel('output_file.xlsx', index=False)
```